# JQuery - Removing Dynamically Created Table with Static Link

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, append

I've got a page where there are two links - Enrolled and Completed. Clicking on either creates a table with the relevant data. When the button is clicked, the current table needs to be removed from the page, and the new one created (via Javascript) and appended. For some reason, `.remove()` and `.empty()` aren't working on the dynamically created table. The Enrolled and Completed links always exist on the page.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <a id="completed" class="btn" title="Completed">Completed</a>
    <a id="enrolled" class="btn" title="Enrolled">Enrolled</a>
    <div id="table_container">
        <table id="courses_table"></table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[class*=btn]").click(function(e) { 
        display_type = this.id; 

        getTags(display_type);

        e.preventDefault();
    }); 
});

function getTags(type) {
    $('#courses_table').remove();

    //ajax call to get data, create string of new table html, append it to the container div
    var table_data = '<table id="courses_table">...</table>';

    $('#table_container').append(table_data);
}
```

I've tried moving the `.remove()` into the click event or the success function, and removing the entire containing div, but no joy. There are no issues w/ the append. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Edit: console.log of `#table_container.children()` is `[img images/calendars.png, div.width-100, table#courses_table]`.

A console.log of `#courses_table` gets me `[table#courses_table]`. If I'm interpreting those results correctly, the table exists, so I'm back to why it's not being removed.

Edit the second: I forgot to mention that the table I'm trying to remove has multiple tbody tags. Perhaps that's causing a problem? I did try and empty the table before removing it, but it didn't work.

Here's a fiddle showing what I'm seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/c4Y3U/13/

Comment: I notice that you have a typo in your HTML: `<table id="courses_table>` (missing closing quote)

Comment: Ahh, that was a copy/paste failure. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Use `console.log` to see what the result of the `$('#courses_table')` DOM query is.  If there's nothing there, check `$('#table_container').children()`.  You need to step through the process to determine where the breakdown is.

Comment: The example also declares `var table_data`, but your `append` is using `table_html`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Calvin.Allen - another typo, fixed

Comment: @NRohler - console.log results added.

Comment: If the table is the only thing inside the `<div>`, you could use `.empty()` instead of `.remove()` - http://jsfiddle.net/CalvinAllen83/c4Y3U/

Comment: @Calvin.Allen - Yeah, I've tried that too and the same thing happens. The original table remains and the new one gets added below it.

Comment: Really?  The jsfiddle I linked to is doing that, and it appears to work.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your fiddle, but no joy for me. My containing div actually does have other content (an image), but I tried emptying it for kicks. The image disappears, but the table remains. One item I forgot to note is that the table has multiple tbody tags - can you think of any reason that might be affecting the remove?

Comment: What about leaving the table intact, and just replacing the content? http://jsfiddle.net/CalvinAllen83/c4Y3U/3/

Comment: @Calvin.Allen - tried that too, the table doesn't empty.

Comment: Try this, made the getTags function internal to the document ready function: http://jsfiddle.net/CalvinAllen83/e94nK/

Comment: Looks like I actually had the table_data declared as a global javascript variable. Declaring it inside the ajax success function (like I had in my above example) and using your last update fixed the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
id="courses_table"
```

use

```
class="courses_table"
```

and of course update jQuery selectors accordingly, see http://jsfiddle.net/c4Y3U/22/